# How to add a "company name" as a user value for permissions and a data variable

Tags: users, hooks

I am creating a site that allows multiple different company's access to separate resources. Access to resources is dependent on the user's role and the company they are registered to.

Sample User Roles:
Mechanic
Scheduler
Parts Distributor
Driver
Admin

Sample Company's:
Joe's Auto Repair
Car Repair USA
Pro Tire & Oil

Each user has access to only his company's data and the data that is associated with the permissions attached to his role.

How can this be done? Am I going to need to code custom modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article can be helpful for you: https://www.drupal.org/node/200631, and you can try [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module to implement it.
Or another way you can try [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) - its more powerful.

Comment: Your answer was a good one although the article you referenced contains a tutorial that is outdated and does not work. I have tried Organic Groups but I keep getting a database error. I am going to try OG again, but it looks like I might just have to create some case-specific modules for this project.

Comment: Yep, the article is outdated, but it shows the main idea. It strange that you have an error with Organic group, its very popular module and really powerful (but more complicated)

Comment: I fixed the organic group error and I am not working on it.

Comment: I gave you the correct answer as I believe that Organic Groups is the best path to take to achieve what I am trying to do.